# CollapsingToolbar back button does not show

Tags: android, android-design-library

I been using the design library and I came across a problem.

```
 final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

I initialized the Toolbar to have to back button, however it only shows in Genymotion Nexus 6. On my LG G2 Lolipop, the back button does not show. Is there a workaround for this bug? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Rather, you should set the up icon on the toolbar.

Use:

`toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_icon));`

You can also set the navigation icon in the xml layout of your toolbar by using the `android:navigationIcon` tag.

Comment: With CollapsingToolbar that does not put the button in the right place.

Comment: `android:navigationIcon` only works in API 21 and above.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed a version in build.gradle from

> compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'

to

> compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'

and added this to class:

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.mainToolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

Now back button is working!